# Where can I place tc filters?

Tags: networking, tc, htb

I have a raspberry pi router for me and my room mates.  The bandwidth is divided as follow:

```
         1:0(htb)
            |
         1:1(16mbit/s)
          /   \
1:2(8mbit/s) 1:ffff(8mbit/s)
```

If I add the filter for with parent 1:0 `(tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 0x0002 fw flowid 1:2)`, it works like a charm.  However, if I add the filter upon class 1:1 the command didn't report any errors but there is no ouput for `tc filter show dev wlan0` command.

**Questions:**
1. Why it didn't work when I put the filters on 1:1?
2. Can I place the filters on subclasses like 1:1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The filters are attached to root of ingress queue discipline, not to classes. So in your case all filters should be created with `parent 1:0` option.
2. To pass the traffic through classes you should create a filter with `flowid ...` or `classid ...` options for every class. So, in your case the filters should be looks like (if I've understood you correctly):

```
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 0x0002 fw flowid 1:2
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 2 handle 0xffff fw flowid 1:ffff
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is there any cases that filters need to be configured with other parents?

Comment: Theoretically you can attach the filters to the non-root qdisc (queue disciplines on leaves classes). Practically it can be useful for flow filter and sfq qdiscs.